# UILabel doesn't show up in my application

Tags: ios, swift

First image shows what's on my storyboard, second image shows what's on my simulator. Label won't show up. I try to add missing constrains and all that, still doesn't work. Besides the label, I only have a map view , nothing else.

[image: Fist image]
[image: Second image]

Comment: It looks like the label may be under the map view.  What constraints have you set on the label and on the map view.  What is the order in the navigator on the left?

Comment: label is on top of the map view, but still doesn't work. It's interesting, when I open the app, the label would appear, and suddenly disappear.

Comment: You can use Debug->View Debugging->Capture View Hierarchy in Xcode to examine what has ended up where

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/dualax7w7i6j6ap/apture%20View%20Hierarchy.mov?dl=0  Please check.

Comment: You can see from that that your label is behind the map view.  Items that are lower in the list on the left are in the front.  Also, what constraints have you set on the label? - It seems to be mis-positioned

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/d4n425x0mwr38rr/AADc7F5SBA2wabKjJ7KyD8KIa?dl=0 I took a screen shot of my constrain, what do you think?

Comment: What are your label's constraints?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/bulkxl905kf1oex/Screen%20Shot%202016-06-16%20at%208.42.11%20PM.png?dl=0

Comment: That is the add new constraints dialog.  It doesn't show what constraints have actually been added to the label.  It looks like there are none, but you an see them in the object inspector by selecting the "ruler"

Comment: You know what? I will give you my source code directly. Please help me fix this, i all be greatly appreciated. https://www.dropbox.com/s/et1po6lnv38le0v/Archive.zip?dl=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove your label's constraint.

Add new constraints that I am suggesting to your label.

1) Center Horizontally
[image]

2) Add Height

[image]

3) Add bottom space / vertical spacing it will show

[image]

4) update Constraints

[image]

It will look something like this..

[image]

Answer (score 0):

your viewDidLoad() method add this line...

```
self.view.bringSubviewToFront(yourLbl)
```

i hope this help you

Comment: Thank you for your help, but it still doesn't work. Check out my source code if you want, this is a really storage problem. https://www.dropbox.com/s/et1po6lnv38le0v/Archive.zip?dl=0